# Bigcommerce Display different images based on sku

Tags: java, image, bigcommerce

I am trying to display a different size chart for each of out pages, mens womens tops bottoms. I tried to create separate templates, but the way BC works the productdetails page cannot really be changed based on the GLOBALS.

Is there a way to use JAVA to read the first 5 digits of a sku to display a certain image or link to open the image in a lightbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create separate product page templates to do this. All you need to do is hide/show them based on the current SKU.

The code you need is something like this:

```
<!-- Current Bigcommerce Theme Code at Panels/ProductAddToCart.html -->
<div class="DetailRow ProductSKU" style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideSKU%%">
  <div class="Label">%%LNG_SKU%%:</div>
    <div class="Value">
      <span class="VariationProductSKU">
        %%GLOBAL_SKU%%
      </span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Place this code where you want the size chart to appear -->
<div id="SizeChart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sizeChartImages = {
  'SKU-1' : 'http://placehold.it/400x200/000?text=Size+Chart+1',
  'SKU-2' : 'http://placehold.it/400x200/000?text=Size+Chart+2',
  'SKU-3' : 'http://placehold.it/400x200/000?text=Size+Chart+3',
  'SKU-4' : 'http://placehold.it/400x200/000?text=Size+Chart+4',
  'SKU-5' : 'http://placehold.it/400x200/000?text=Size+Chart+5'
}

var currentSKU = $('.ProductSKU .VariationProductSKU').text();
$.each( sizeChartImages, function( sku, url ) {
  if(currentSKU.includes(sku)) {
    $('#SizeChart').append('<img src="' + url + '"/>')
  }
});
</script>
```

You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/rshwwxyc/

Comment: Thank you so much jeremy! I am trying to teach myself JS right now, I am trying to figure out if I can use a startswith() to read the first 5 digits to show the appropriate sizechart. This is so much help though!

Comment: You shouldn't need a different function to read the first 5 digits because I have used the javascript function "includes()" which tests whether a string includes another string. Just open the jsfiddle link I provided to test the code with your actual SKUs instead of the examples I used. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

Comment: If you do specifically need to test the first 5 digits, startswith() should work fine. Just change the 5th line from the bottom to `if(sku.startsWith(currentSKU) {`

Comment: @NealMunroe please accept this answer if you believe it has helped solve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: this worked perfect thank you for your help, one more question though...... How would I use this code to display a link that, that would open up this image in a lightbox, instead of displaying the image?